# Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi i'm getting error while running Selenium web driver , please help to resolve

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Element must be user-editable in order to clear it. Command duration
>   or timeout: 103 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision:
>   '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58' System info: host: 'anil-PC',
>   ip: '192.168.0.131', os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86',
>   os.version: '6.0', java.version: '1.7.0-ea' Session ID:
>   0736ad53-a638-44e4-a24a-bcda63bb6f4e Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   version=43.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true,
>   handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:531)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.clear(RemoteWebElement.java:140)
>     at demo.TestFB.main(TestFB.java:26) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element must be user-editable
>   in order to clear it. Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision:
>   '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58' System info: host: 'anil-PC',
>   ip: '192.168.0.131', os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86',
>   os.version: '6.0', java.version: '1.7.0-ea' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown   at .bot.Error(file:///C:/Users/anil/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9127022654718385403webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:681)
>     at .bot.action.clear(file:///C:/Users/anil/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9127022654718385403webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11685)
>     at .WebElement.clearElement(file:///C:/Users/anil/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9127022654718385403webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12136)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/anil/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9127022654718385403webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/anil/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9127022654718385403webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/anil/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9127022654718385403webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

Comment: What's your question? You haven't provided any code that we can examine. Did you google the error message? What did you find? What did you try to adjust in your code? Please add a lot more detail on what your scenario is, what you have tried, and what the result was.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling clear() on an element that is not user editable, so an element that is not an input or textarea.

> Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

From the selenium java docs about clear()

```
/**
   * If this element is a text entry element, this will clear the value. Has no effect on other
   * elements. Text entry elements are INPUT and TEXTAREA elements.
   *
   * Note that the events fired by this event may not be as you'd expect.  In particular, we don't
   * fire any keyboard or mouse events.  If you want to ensure keyboard events are fired, consider
   * using something like {@link #sendKeys(CharSequence...)} with the backspace key.  To ensure
   * you get a change event, consider following with a call to {@link #sendKeys(CharSequence...)}
   * with the tab key.
   */
```